# Start a docker container based on condition

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Problem-**

I have a docker-compose.yml with 6 services. When i execute docker-compose up, all 6 containers gets started but i need 2 containers to start its work initially and rest 4 containers based on conditions.

**Description-**

6 services in compose(2 services for all users & 4 services for 2 users):-

-2 service for all users

- I'm mounting login required pages in first container
- I maintained database for login accounts in 2nd container

-2 services for each users

- Based on the user, i redirect from login page to different applications
- at this point, i mounted his/her application in one container and database in another.

**Is there a way, when i run docker-compose up -it should start only 2 services common to all users and based on the user login i need to start other 2 services where his/her application mounted ???**

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand but it looks like you want to create one or two containers per user.That's very resource inefficient and not what containers are for. Containers are the building blocks of a service to be used by many users.
As for having containers starting based on other containers, you can currently use a script like https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: This is beyond the scope of docker-compose. It's not really the docker way, but you could write your own API for this and it would work ok. Given you have only 2 users why not just fire up everything anyway?

Comment: you're trying to build a micro-service architecture, but doing this in absolutely wrong way. If I understand your intentions correctly, you should decouple 2 and 2 (2 sets of 2 service for each user,2x2=4) services, split the docker-composer and run them when you need them using your own api, as @Matthew suggested above

Answer (score 12):

This can now be solved neatly, with a recent addition to docker-compose, compose profiles (at least for the service part, not sure for the volumes). [See documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/).

Comment: Was it already supported in the previous `docker-compose` (V1)? As in https://stackoverflow.com/q/67652020/6309?

Comment: Actually yes, it's supported in both V1 and V2

Comment: Thank you for getting back and checking this out.

Answer (score 6):

Doing this based upon user alone would require logic outside of Docker Compose, but you may be able to configure .

#### Extending Services

You might be able to use two Docker Compose files to accomplish similar results.

- 2 services for all users - docker-compose.yml
- 4 services for 2 users - docker-compose.admin.yml

In `docker-compose.admin.yml` would **compliment** or **override** settings in the original compose file, as well as additional containers. You can use overrides to change anything including ENV vars or volumes sent to the containers.

When running `docker-compose up` the two services for all users will start.

You can run all six containers by running

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.admin.yml up
```

#### Aliases

Setting up an alias in your `.bashrc` would make this much easier to use on a daily basis.

```
# For regular users
alias comp="docker-compose"

# For two special users
alias comp="docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.admin.yml"
```

With this setup all users can use `comp up` or `comp down` and get the appropriate set of containers.

#### Docs

See details in the Docker Docs:

[Extending Service in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)

Answer (score 2):

I often have some services that are no-ops based on the environment.

If you add this you will pass through the external user to the container:

```
    environment:
      - USER=${USER}
    entrypoint: ./my_entrypoint_conditional_wrapper.sh
```

In the entrypoint script, check the `USER` variable, and if the service should NOT start, simply `exit 0`, otherwise run the original entrypoint.

If the image you are using is one you didn't build, you can always use `volumes` to pass-through just the script:

```
    volumes:
      - ./my_entrypoint_conditional_wrapper.sh: /tmp/./my_entrypoint_conditional_wrapper.sh
    entrypoint: /tmp/my_entrypoint_conditional_wrapper.sh
```