# docker compose command to run with profiles

Tags: docker, docker-compose

With the recent update of docker, whenever I run `docker-compose up -d` docker engine suggest me with the following line:

> Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

Question is how can I run `docker compose` command with profile option?
For example, in `docker-compose` I can use profiles as `docker-compose --profile dev up`.
Is there a similar thing in `docker compose` too?

I looked into the CLI [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/) but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`docker compose`  has `profile` option. Try executing `docker compose --help` in your terminal and you will see the below help section with the option of `profile`

```sh
╰>>> docker compose --help

Usage:  docker compose [OPTIONS] COMMAND

Docker Compose

Options:
      --ansi string                Control when to print ANSI control characters ("never"|"always"|"auto") (default "auto")
      --env-file string            Specify an alternate environment file.
  -f, --file stringArray           Compose configuration files
      --profile stringArray        Specify a profile to enable
      --project-directory string   Specify an alternate working directory
                                   (default: the path of the Compose file)
  -p, --project-name string        Project name

Commands:
  build       Build or rebuild services
  convert     Converts the compose file to platform's canonical format
  create      Creates containers for a service.
  down        Stop and remove containers, networks
  events      Receive real time events from containers.
  exec        Execute a command in a running container.
  images      List images used by the created containers
  kill        Force stop service containers.
  logs        View output from containers
  ls          List running compose projects
  pause       pause services
  port        Print the public port for a port binding.
  ps          List containers
  pull        Pull service images
  push        Push service images
  restart     Restart containers
  rm          Removes stopped service containers
  run         Run a one-off command on a service.
  start       Start services
  stop        Stop services
  top         Display the running processes
  unpause     unpause services
  up          Create and start containers

Run 'docker compose COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```

If your docker CLI doesn't have this option maybe you will have to upgrade your docker CLI.

Here is the [Docker CLI documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose/) with `--profile` option.

Comment: Yes. Apparently the `--profile` option is documented at the parent command. It helped, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I just noticed it. I'll update my answer with it.